# Profiling a hooked assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, profiling, hook

I want to do a performance analysis via VS2010 for a hooked assembly. The host process is started by a third application which performs the hook, so I cannot simply start the host exe with the profiling tool.

I already managed to attach the VS2010 debugger to the host process to debug my assembly. How do I run the profiling tool? Is there a way to call the profiler from within the assembly?

Thanks in advance for your help